# How do I stack the images above the text?

Tags: javascript, html, css, styles

I am trying to figure out how do I stack each of the images above the text? The way it is currently it is it produces each image on the same line as the associated text so I am trying to do the opposite and stack it.

```
  <div class="flash-infos">   
    <div class="flash-info truck">
      <svg version="1.1" id="Capa_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" viewBox="0 0 491.1 491.1" style="enable-background:new 0 0 491.1 491.1;" xml:space="preserve"> <path transform="translate(0 -540.36)" d="M401.5,863.31c-12,0-23.4,4.7-32,13.2c-8.6,8.6-13.4,19.8-13.4,31.8s4.7,23.2,13.4,31.8 c8.7,8.5,20,13.2,32,13.2c24.6,0,44.6-20.2,44.6-45S426.1,863.31,401.5,863.31z M401.5,933.31c-13.8,0-25.4-11.4-25.4-25 s11.6-25,25.4-25c13.6,0,24.6,11.2,24.6,25S415.1,933.31,401.5,933.31z M413.1,713.41c-1.8-1.7-4.2-2.6-6.7-2.6h-51.3 c-5.5,0-10,4.5-10,10v82c0,5.5,4.5,10,10,10h81.4c5.5,0,10-4.5,10-10v-54.9c0-2.8-1.2-5.5-3.3-7.4L413.1,713.41z M426.5,792.81 h-61.4v-62.1h37.4l24,21.6V792.81z M157.3,863.31c-12,0-23.4,4.7-32,13.2c-8.6,8.6-13.4,19.8-13.4,31.8s4.7,23.2,13.4,31.8 c8.7,8.5,20,13.2,32,13.2c24.6,0,44.6-20.2,44.6-45S181.9,863.31,157.3,863.31z M157.3,933.31c-13.8,0-25.4-11.4-25.4-25 s11.6-25,25.4-25c13.6,0,24.6,11.2,24.6,25S170.9,933.31,157.3,933.31z M90.6,875.61H70.5v-26.6c0-5.5-4.5-10-10-10s-10,4.5-10,10 v36.6c0,5.5,4.5,10,10,10h30.1c5.5,0,10-4.5,10-10S96.1,875.61,90.6,875.61z M141.3,821.11c0-5.5-4.5-10-10-10H10 c-5.5,0-10,4.5-10,10s4.5,10,10,10h121.3C136.8,831.11,141.3,826.71,141.3,821.11z M30.3,785.01l121.3,0.7c5.5,0,10-4.4,10.1-9.9 c0.1-5.6-4.4-10.1-9.9-10.1l-121.3-0.7c-0.1,0-0.1,0-0.1,0c-5.5,0-10,4.4-10,9.9C20.3,780.51,24.8,785.01,30.3,785.01z M50.7,739.61 H172c5.5,0,10-4.5,10-10s-4.5-10-10-10H50.7c-5.5,0-10,4.5-10,10S45.2,739.61,50.7,739.61z M487.4,726.11L487.4,726.11l-71.6-59.3 c-1.8-1.5-4-2.3-6.4-2.3h-84.2v-36c0-5.5-4.5-10-10-10H60.5c-5.5,0-10,4.5-10,10v73.2c0,5.5,4.5,10,10,10s10-4.5,10-10v-63.2h234.8 v237.1h-82c-5.5,0-10,4.5-10,10s4.5,10,10,10h122.1c5.5,0,10-4.5,10-10s-4.5-10-10-10h-20.1v-191.1h80.6l65.2,54l-0.7,136.9H460 c-5.5,0-10,4.5-10,10s4.5,10,10,10h20.3c5.5,0,10-4.4,10-9.9l0.8-151.6C491,730.91,489.7,728.01,487.4,726.11z"/> <g> </g> <g> </g> <g> </g> <g> </g> <g> </g> <g> </g> <g> </g> <g> </g> <g> </g> <g> </g> <g> </g> <g> </g> <g> </g> <g> </g> <g> </g> </svg>
      Free shipping
    </div>
  </div>
  


 <style>
   .flash-infos {
     padding:6px 10px;
     background:#333;
     color:#FFF;
     display:flex;
     width:100%;
     max-width:100%;
     align-items:center;
     
   }
    .flash-info  {
      padding:0;
      display:flex !important;
      align-items:center;
      justify-content:center;
    }
    .flash-info svg {
      fill:#FFF;
      margin-right:7px;
      width:auto;
      height:28px;
    } 
    .flash-info.truck svg  {
      height:30px;
    }
    .flash-info-pulse {
      animation: flash-pulse 2s infinite;
    }
    @keyframes flash-pulse {
      0% {
        opacity:0;
      }
      
      50% {
        opacity:1;
      }

      100% {
        opacity:1;
      }
    }
  </style>
```

Comment: Can you share the custom CSS that you have defined?

Comment: @chris05 I updated the question to include the custom CSS.

Answer (score 1):

Just add `flex-direction:column` on your element .flash-info

```html
<div class="flash-infos">   
    <div class="flash-info truck">
      <svg version="1.1" id="Capa_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" viewBox="0 0 491.1 491.1" style="enable-background:new 0 0 491.1 491.1;" xml:space="preserve"> <path transform="translate(0 -540.36)" d="M401.5,863.31c-12,0-23.4,4.7-32,13.2c-8.6,8.6-13.4,19.8-13.4,31.8s4.7,23.2,13.4,31.8 c8.7,8.5,20,13.2,32,13.2c24.6,0,44.6-20.2,44.6-45S426.1,863.31,401.5,863.31z M401.5,933.31c-13.8,0-25.4-11.4-25.4-25 s11.6-25,25.4-25c13.6,0,24.6,11.2,24.6,25S415.1,933.31,401.5,933.31z M413.1,713.41c-1.8-1.7-4.2-2.6-6.7-2.6h-51.3 c-5.5,0-10,4.5-10,10v82c0,5.5,4.5,10,10,10h81.4c5.5,0,10-4.5,10-10v-54.9c0-2.8-1.2-5.5-3.3-7.4L413.1,713.41z M426.5,792.81 h-61.4v-62.1h37.4l24,21.6V792.81z M157.3,863.31c-12,0-23.4,4.7-32,13.2c-8.6,8.6-13.4,19.8-13.4,31.8s4.7,23.2,13.4,31.8 c8.7,8.5,20,13.2,32,13.2c24.6,0,44.6-20.2,44.6-45S181.9,863.31,157.3,863.31z M157.3,933.31c-13.8,0-25.4-11.4-25.4-25 s11.6-25,25.4-25c13.6,0,24.6,11.2,24.6,25S170.9,933.31,157.3,933.31z M90.6,875.61H70.5v-26.6c0-5.5-4.5-10-10-10s-10,4.5-10,10 v36.6c0,5.5,4.5,10,10,10h30.1c5.5,0,10-4.5,10-10S96.1,875.61,90.6,875.61z M141.3,821.11c0-5.5-4.5-10-10-10H10 c-5.5,0-10,4.5-10,10s4.5,10,10,10h121.3C136.8,831.11,141.3,826.71,141.3,821.11z M30.3,785.01l121.3,0.7c5.5,0,10-4.4,10.1-9.9 c0.1-5.6-4.4-10.1-9.9-10.1l-121.3-0.7c-0.1,0-0.1,0-0.1,0c-5.5,0-10,4.4-10,9.9C20.3,780.51,24.8,785.01,30.3,785.01z M50.7,739.61 H172c5.5,0,10-4.5,10-10s-4.5-10-10-10H50.7c-5.5,0-10,4.5-10,10S45.2,739.61,50.7,739.61z M487.4,726.11L487.4,726.11l-71.6-59.3 c-1.8-1.5-4-2.3-6.4-2.3h-84.2v-36c0-5.5-4.5-10-10-10H60.5c-5.5,0-10,4.5-10,10v73.2c0,5.5,4.5,10,10,10s10-4.5,10-10v-63.2h234.8 v237.1h-82c-5.5,0-10,4.5-10,10s4.5,10,10,10h122.1c5.5,0,10-4.5,10-10s-4.5-10-10-10h-20.1v-191.1h80.6l65.2,54l-0.7,136.9H460 c-5.5,0-10,4.5-10,10s4.5,10,10,10h20.3c5.5,0,10-4.4,10-9.9l0.8-151.6C491,730.91,489.7,728.01,487.4,726.11z"/> <g> </g> <g> </g> <g> </g> <g> </g> <g> </g> <g> </g> <g> </g> <g> </g> <g> </g> <g> </g> <g> </g> <g> </g> <g> </g> <g> </g> <g> </g> </svg>
      Free shipping
    </div>
  </div>
  


 <style>
   .flash-infos {
     padding:6px 10px;
     background:#333;
     color:#FFF;
     display:flex;
     width:100%;
     max-width:100%;
     align-items:center;
     
   }
    .flash-info  {
      padding:0;
      display:flex !important;
      align-items:center;
      justify-content:center;
      flex-direction:column;
    }
    .flash-info svg {
      fill:#FFF;
      margin-right:7px;
      width:auto;
      height:28px;
    } 
    .flash-info.truck svg  {
      height:30px;
    }
    .flash-info-pulse {
      animation: flash-pulse 2s infinite;
    }
    @keyframes flash-pulse {
      0% {
        opacity:0;
      }
      
      50% {
        opacity:1;
      }

      100% {
        opacity:1;
      }
    }
  </style>
```

Comment: This worked perfect, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you want a multiple containers siblings display as `flex`, You give the property to the parent... as you have done, but it makes no sense to give the same propertie to this containers (even with `!important`), just remove it and give the `svg's` `display block` so they take the full width (they are `inline` by default).

Like this:

```css
.flash-infos {
     padding:6px 10px;
     background:#333;
     color:#FFF;
     display:flex;
     width:100%;
     max-width:100%;
     align-items:center;
     
   }
    .flash-info  {
      padding:0;
      align-items:center;
      justify-content:center;
    }
    .flash-info svg {
      fill:#FFF;
      margin-right:7px;
      width:auto;
      height:28px;
      display:block;
    } 
    .flash-info.truck svg  {
      height:30px;
    }
    .flash-info-pulse {
      animation: flash-pulse 2s infinite;
    }
    @keyframes flash-pulse {
      0% {
        opacity:0;
      }
      
      50% {
        opacity:1;
      }

      100% {
        opacity:1;
      }
    }
```

```html
  <div class="flash-infos">   
    <div class="flash-info truck">
      <svg version="1.1" id="Capa_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" viewBox="0 0 491.1 491.1" style="enable-background:new 0 0 491.1 491.1;" xml:space="preserve"> <path transform="translate(0 -540.36)" d="M401.5,863.31c-12,0-23.4,4.7-32,13.2c-8.6,8.6-13.4,19.8-13.4,31.8s4.7,23.2,13.4,31.8 c8.7,8.5,20,13.2,32,13.2c24.6,0,44.6-20.2,44.6-45S426.1,863.31,401.5,863.31z M401.5,933.31c-13.8,0-25.4-11.4-25.4-25 s11.6-25,25.4-25c13.6,0,24.6,11.2,24.6,25S415.1,933.31,401.5,933.31z M413.1,713.41c-1.8-1.7-4.2-2.6-6.7-2.6h-51.3 c-5.5,0-10,4.5-10,10v82c0,5.5,4.5,10,10,10h81.4c5.5,0,10-4.5,10-10v-54.9c0-2.8-1.2-5.5-3.3-7.4L413.1,713.41z M426.5,792.81 h-61.4v-62.1h37.4l24,21.6V792.81z M157.3,863.31c-12,0-23.4,4.7-32,13.2c-8.6,8.6-13.4,19.8-13.4,31.8s4.7,23.2,13.4,31.8 c8.7,8.5,20,13.2,32,13.2c24.6,0,44.6-20.2,44.6-45S181.9,863.31,157.3,863.31z M157.3,933.31c-13.8,0-25.4-11.4-25.4-25 s11.6-25,25.4-25c13.6,0,24.6,11.2,24.6,25S170.9,933.31,157.3,933.31z M90.6,875.61H70.5v-26.6c0-5.5-4.5-10-10-10s-10,4.5-10,10 v36.6c0,5.5,4.5,10,10,10h30.1c5.5,0,10-4.5,10-10S96.1,875.61,90.6,875.61z M141.3,821.11c0-5.5-4.5-10-10-10H10 c-5.5,0-10,4.5-10,10s4.5,10,10,10h121.3C136.8,831.11,141.3,826.71,141.3,821.11z M30.3,785.01l121.3,0.7c5.5,0,10-4.4,10.1-9.9 c0.1-5.6-4.4-10.1-9.9-10.1l-121.3-0.7c-0.1,0-0.1,0-0.1,0c-5.5,0-10,4.4-10,9.9C20.3,780.51,24.8,785.01,30.3,785.01z M50.7,739.61 H172c5.5,0,10-4.5,10-10s-4.5-10-10-10H50.7c-5.5,0-10,4.5-10,10S45.2,739.61,50.7,739.61z M487.4,726.11L487.4,726.11l-71.6-59.3 c-1.8-1.5-4-2.3-6.4-2.3h-84.2v-36c0-5.5-4.5-10-10-10H60.5c-5.5,0-10,4.5-10,10v73.2c0,5.5,4.5,10,10,10s10-4.5,10-10v-63.2h234.8 v237.1h-82c-5.5,0-10,4.5-10,10s4.5,10,10,10h122.1c5.5,0,10-4.5,10-10s-4.5-10-10-10h-20.1v-191.1h80.6l65.2,54l-0.7,136.9H460 c-5.5,0-10,4.5-10,10s4.5,10,10,10h20.3c5.5,0,10-4.4,10-9.9l0.8-151.6C491,730.91,489.7,728.01,487.4,726.11z"/> <g> </g> <g> </g> <g> </g> <g> </g> <g> </g> <g> </g> <g> </g> <g> </g> <g> </g> <g> </g> <g> </g> <g> </g> <g> </g> <g> </g> <g> </g> </svg>
      Free shipping
    </div>
    <div class="flash-info truck">
      <svg version="1.1" id="Capa_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" viewBox="0 0 491.1 491.1" style="enable-background:new 0 0 491.1 491.1;" xml:space="preserve"> <path transform="translate(0 -540.36)" d="M401.5,863.31c-12,0-23.4,4.7-32,13.2c-8.6,8.6-13.4,19.8-13.4,31.8s4.7,23.2,13.4,31.8 c8.7,8.5,20,13.2,32,13.2c24.6,0,44.6-20.2,44.6-45S426.1,863.31,401.5,863.31z M401.5,933.31c-13.8,0-25.4-11.4-25.4-25 s11.6-25,25.4-25c13.6,0,24.6,11.2,24.6,25S415.1,933.31,401.5,933.31z M413.1,713.41c-1.8-1.7-4.2-2.6-6.7-2.6h-51.3 c-5.5,0-10,4.5-10,10v82c0,5.5,4.5,10,10,10h81.4c5.5,0,10-4.5,10-10v-54.9c0-2.8-1.2-5.5-3.3-7.4L413.1,713.41z M426.5,792.81 h-61.4v-62.1h37.4l24,21.6V792.81z M157.3,863.31c-12,0-23.4,4.7-32,13.2c-8.6,8.6-13.4,19.8-13.4,31.8s4.7,23.2,13.4,31.8 c8.7,8.5,20,13.2,32,13.2c24.6,0,44.6-20.2,44.6-45S181.9,863.31,157.3,863.31z M157.3,933.31c-13.8,0-25.4-11.4-25.4-25 s11.6-25,25.4-25c13.6,0,24.6,11.2,24.6,25S170.9,933.31,157.3,933.31z M90.6,875.61H70.5v-26.6c0-5.5-4.5-10-10-10s-10,4.5-10,10 v36.6c0,5.5,4.5,10,10,10h30.1c5.5,0,10-4.5,10-10S96.1,875.61,90.6,875.61z M141.3,821.11c0-5.5-4.5-10-10-10H10 c-5.5,0-10,4.5-10,10s4.5,10,10,10h121.3C136.8,831.11,141.3,826.71,141.3,821.11z M30.3,785.01l121.3,0.7c5.5,0,10-4.4,10.1-9.9 c0.1-5.6-4.4-10.1-9.9-10.1l-121.3-0.7c-0.1,0-0.1,0-0.1,0c-5.5,0-10,4.4-10,9.9C20.3,780.51,24.8,785.01,30.3,785.01z M50.7,739.61 H172c5.5,0,10-4.5,10-10s-4.5-10-10-10H50.7c-5.5,0-10,4.5-10,10S45.2,739.61,50.7,739.61z M487.4,726.11L487.4,726.11l-71.6-59.3 c-1.8-1.5-4-2.3-6.4-2.3h-84.2v-36c0-5.5-4.5-10-10-10H60.5c-5.5,0-10,4.5-10,10v73.2c0,5.5,4.5,10,10,10s10-4.5,10-10v-63.2h234.8 v237.1h-82c-5.5,0-10,4.5-10,10s4.5,10,10,10h122.1c5.5,0,10-4.5,10-10s-4.5-10-10-10h-20.1v-191.1h80.6l65.2,54l-0.7,136.9H460 c-5.5,0-10,4.5-10,10s4.5,10,10,10h20.3c5.5,0,10-4.4,10-9.9l0.8-151.6C491,730.91,489.7,728.01,487.4,726.11z"/> <g> </g> <g> </g> <g> </g> <g> </g> <g> </g> <g> </g> <g> </g> <g> </g> <g> </g> <g> </g> <g> </g> <g> </g> <g> </g> <g> </g> <g> </g> </svg>
      Free shipping
    </div>
    <div class="flash-info truck">
      <svg version="1.1" id="Capa_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" viewBox="0 0 491.1 491.1" style="enable-background:new 0 0 491.1 491.1;" xml:space="preserve"> <path transform="translate(0 -540.36)" d="M401.5,863.31c-12,0-23.4,4.7-32,13.2c-8.6,8.6-13.4,19.8-13.4,31.8s4.7,23.2,13.4,31.8 c8.7,8.5,20,13.2,32,13.2c24.6,0,44.6-20.2,44.6-45S426.1,863.31,401.5,863.31z M401.5,933.31c-13.8,0-25.4-11.4-25.4-25 s11.6-25,25.4-25c13.6,0,24.6,11.2,24.6,25S415.1,933.31,401.5,933.31z M413.1,713.41c-1.8-1.7-4.2-2.6-6.7-2.6h-51.3 c-5.5,0-10,4.5-10,10v82c0,5.5,4.5,10,10,10h81.4c5.5,0,10-4.5,10-10v-54.9c0-2.8-1.2-5.5-3.3-7.4L413.1,713.41z M426.5,792.81 h-61.4v-62.1h37.4l24,21.6V792.81z M157.3,863.31c-12,0-23.4,4.7-32,13.2c-8.6,8.6-13.4,19.8-13.4,31.8s4.7,23.2,13.4,31.8 c8.7,8.5,20,13.2,32,13.2c24.6,0,44.6-20.2,44.6-45S181.9,863.31,157.3,863.31z M157.3,933.31c-13.8,0-25.4-11.4-25.4-25 s11.6-25,25.4-25c13.6,0,24.6,11.2,24.6,25S170.9,933.31,157.3,933.31z M90.6,875.61H70.5v-26.6c0-5.5-4.5-10-10-10s-10,4.5-10,10 v36.6c0,5.5,4.5,10,10,10h30.1c5.5,0,10-4.5,10-10S96.1,875.61,90.6,875.61z M141.3,821.11c0-5.5-4.5-10-10-10H10 c-5.5,0-10,4.5-10,10s4.5,10,10,10h121.3C136.8,831.11,141.3,826.71,141.3,821.11z M30.3,785.01l121.3,0.7c5.5,0,10-4.4,10.1-9.9 c0.1-5.6-4.4-10.1-9.9-10.1l-121.3-0.7c-0.1,0-0.1,0-0.1,0c-5.5,0-10,4.4-10,9.9C20.3,780.51,24.8,785.01,30.3,785.01z M50.7,739.61 H172c5.5,0,10-4.5,10-10s-4.5-10-10-10H50.7c-5.5,0-10,4.5-10,10S45.2,739.61,50.7,739.61z M487.4,726.11L487.4,726.11l-71.6-59.3 c-1.8-1.5-4-2.3-6.4-2.3h-84.2v-36c0-5.5-4.5-10-10-10H60.5c-5.5,0-10,4.5-10,10v73.2c0,5.5,4.5,10,10,10s10-4.5,10-10v-63.2h234.8 v237.1h-82c-5.5,0-10,4.5-10,10s4.5,10,10,10h122.1c5.5,0,10-4.5,10-10s-4.5-10-10-10h-20.1v-191.1h80.6l65.2,54l-0.7,136.9H460 c-5.5,0-10,4.5-10,10s4.5,10,10,10h20.3c5.5,0,10-4.4,10-9.9l0.8-151.6C491,730.91,489.7,728.01,487.4,726.11z"/> <g> </g> <g> </g> <g> </g> <g> </g> <g> </g> <g> </g> <g> </g> <g> </g> <g> </g> <g> </g> <g> </g> <g> </g> <g> </g> <g> </g> <g> </g> </svg>
      Free shipping
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: This did not work for me for some reason, the first solution by @hery worked for me